# Context menu not view

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I want to show ContextMenu after clicking on ListView Item. But when i click or
LongClick on Item my ContextMenu not appear. I don't know where is the problem.
Here is my code.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Play");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit"); 
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Rename"); 
    //MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    //inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  }

@Override  
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        if(item.getTitle()=="Play"){playAudio(item.getItemId());}  
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Edit"){editAudio(item.getItemId());}  
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Delete"){deleteAudio(item.getItemId());}
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Rename"){renameAudio(item.getItemId());}
    else {return false;}  
return true;  
}
```

Please give me hint or direct me where is my code wrong?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where are your ItemClick and LongClick Listeners?

Comment: we don't need both method in contextMenu... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you forgot to set it for `ListView`

```
registerForContextMenu(yourListView);
```